# Class child type determining in php

Tags: php, class

Let say I has a base class `Animal` in some plugin's separated code. When I using this plugin, I'm defining child classes, `Cat` and `Dog`, extends `Animal`. I have same constructors so I easily can do like

```
$animal = new Animal($id);
$cat = new Cat($id);
$dog = new Dog($id);
```

The question is - when I just have a ID ( that represents database object ID ) and I need to create an instance of it class, what is the best way to determinate child class type without changing base class code.

I was thinking about create a child class based on instance of parent class like

```
// plugin
class Animal{
 function __construct($id){
  if( $id instanceof Animal ){
   $this = $id;
   return;
  }
  // base class construct
 }
}
// main code
class Cat extends Animal{
 function __construct($id){
  parent::__construct($id);
  // child class construct
 }
}

public function get_animal($id){
 $animal = new Animal($id);
 if( $animal->get_type() == 'Cat')
  return new Cat($animal);
}
```

Does it right?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know what entity is related to ID when you get ID?

Comment: No, at least when I get It. But I know it after executing base class constructor